# How to remotely install SSH on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vps

It seems that my VPS doesn't have SSH installed(I'm not sure yet), because I get no response from the server, and I cant ping it. So I think this is weird, because I cant control my VPS by anyway.

When I try to connect i get connection timeout, and no route to host.
I'm running Ubuntu 12.04LTS.
The way I'm trying to connect is `ssh user@ipv4address`. Hope this helps.

So , I wanted to know:

1. How to make sure I don't have SSH installed on my server?
2. How to install that, is this something should come with the OS template itself?

I tried searching for answers, but I was out of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most VPS providers offer a way to get a remote console on your linux instance.  For instance, if you use Rimuhosting, you would [follow these procedures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OnJRm6M2cQ).

Short answer: Get a remote console on the server and do what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: Well, what if the VPS provider doesn't have a remote console?

Comment: Then you need to get help from your VPS provider to fix whatever is wrong.  Honestly, we can't help at this point if there is no console or network connectivity

Comment: @AzizAG  Get a new VPS provider.